# TestNG intelli-sense not working in Eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, testng

Here is the software, library i am using:

1) Eclipse Neon

2) TestNG - 6.10

3) Maven Project

TestNG intelli-sense not working for me in Testng.xml file. Earlier it was working.
Earlier it was showing suggestions for following tags i.e. methods, method, listener etc.

Can someone faced the same issue.

Here is my testng.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" >
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="x listener" />
</listeners>
<test name="Smoke">
    <parameter name="platform" value="test" />
    <classes>
        <class name="smoke" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: You can try to re-install testNG plugin

Comment: do one thing. right click on project >> TestNG >> Convert to Testng. It will create testng.xml file. try on it

Comment: The above solutions did not work.